# assertRaises in python unit-test not catching the exception

Tags: python, unit-testing, assertraises

Can somebody tell me why the following unit-test is failing on the
ValueError in test_bad, rather than catching it with assertRaises
and succeeding?  I think I'm using the correct procedure and syntax,
but the ValueError is not getting caught.

I'm using Python 2.7.5 on a linux box.

Here is the code …

```
import unittest

class IsOne(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def is_one(self, i):
        if (i != 1):
            raise ValueError

class IsOne_test(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.isone = IsOne()

    def test_good(self):
        self.isone.is_one(1)
        self.assertTrue(True)

    def test_bad(self):
        self.assertRaises(ValueError, self.isone.is_one(2))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

and here is the output of the unit-test:

```
======================================================================
ERROR: test_bad (__main__.IsOne_test)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test/raises.py", line 20, in test_bad
    self.assertRaises(ValueError, self.isone.is_one(2))
  File "test/raises.py", line 8, in is_one
    raise ValueError
ValueError

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.008s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

Answer (score 93):

Unittest's [assertRaises](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertRaises) takes a callable and arguments, so in your case, you'd call it like:

```
self.assertRaises(ValueError, self.isone.is_one, 2)
```

If you prefer, as of Python2.7, you could also use it as a context manager like:

```
with self.assertRaises(ValueError):
    self.isone.is_one(2)
```